# How to setup sonar scans for a project in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, clearcase, release-management

I need to setup sonar scans for a components how should I start this can any one help me at these

Comment: your question is so vague I don't know why you even ask it here when typing "jenkins sonar" gets you thousands of pages answering it in details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer [my case](http://www.tuan.nguoianphu.com/Sonar-step-by-step) :

- Machine A (192.168.1.1): Centos

  - Download and install SonarQube, MySQL http://192.168.1.1:9000
- Machine B (192.168.1.2): Centos

  - SonarQube Runner
  - Jenkins http://192.168.1.2:8080
  - SCM like ClearClear, Git
  - Build tools (JDK, Maven, Ant,...)...

Comment: If you already have maven, I don't see any use in using the SonarRunner.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of links on sonarqube/jenkins site to setup it. you could find it there.